# Are dividends exclusively a part of earnings?

Tags: stocks, dividends, corporate-earnings, stock-dividend

Are stock dividends exclusively part of earnings?  Or are there cases when companies pay dividends despite zero or low earnings?

Comment: The laws on what money can be used to pay dividends vary from country to country. What country do you want to know about?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "Capital Dividend" and arguably it is not a dividend at all.

Comment: @MikeScott I see, it is the general picture I was after

Comment: Dupe https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/52119/do-companies-only-pay-dividends-if-they-are-in-profit and related https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/64237/can-a-company-stop-paying-dividends

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the end it comes out of earnings, **but** the earnings don't have to be made that financial year. So yes you can pay dividends despite negative, zero or low earnings in a specific year. This can be a strategic consideration of the company called dividend continuity.

This is based on German Law (§ 150 AktG), but should be applicable elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 18):

[Cash dividends](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cashdividend.asp) are paid from the company's cash on hand.  It doesn't matter where that money comes from.  You might have earned it that year, previous years, or (rarely and foolishly) borrowed it or retained it from a stock offering, etc.

> A cash dividend is funds or money paid to stockholders **generally** as part of the corporation's current earnings or accumulated profits.

Comment: One quibble - jurisdictional corporate law will often prevent dividends from being paid out of debt / equity offerings. Similar cash payments may be made, but they are likely called something else ['repatriation of capital', or similar].

Comment: "rarely and foolishly" - That seems overly subjective. Corporations in US have been engaging in debt-funded buybacks and dividend recaps for many years since 09. Whether or not that's foolish depends on whose perspective you're taking.

Answer (score 1):

Dividends are actually paid from **Retained earnings** via **Cash** so the process is a step or two removed from direct earnings. This helps to explain how companies can pay a dividend despite “zero or low earnings” or even negative earnings (although this is probably not clever).

Simply, a company can pay a dividend providing it has the cash to pay it.

The decision is up to the board of directors and any number of factors may enter into their reasoning.